# Purpose of rebind in the following container

Tags: c++, c++17, allocator

I am reading some C++ code and specifically trying to understand a customised container.

The container has following the template parameters:

```
 template<typename T, typename Alloc>
 class container{ ... };
```

Where `T` is the type of data like `float` or `int`. The `Alloc` is the allocator and could be one of the standard libraries ones.

Within that container I find following:

```
 class Container{ ....
 template<typename NewType> 
  struct Rebind
   { 
      using newalloc = typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::template rebind_alloc<NewType>; 
      using Other    =       container<NewType, newalloc>
   }
 }
```

I dont find anywhere the struct member of `Rebind` used explicitly at least and I am struggling to understand the purpose of it.

What is the developer trying to achieve by having the struct within the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a data member. It is a template member, that allows code (which is probably itself a template) to get a different container type with a similar allocator.

e.g. applying a function to each element to get a new container of the results

```
template <typename Container, typename Function, typename Result = typename Container::template Rebind<std::invoke_result_t<Function, typename Container::const_reference>>::Other>
Result transform(const Container & container, Function function)
{
    Result result(container.get_allocator());
    for (auto & element : container) { result.push_back(function(element); }
    return result;
}
```